# Reload component when router-link visited

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular-router

I need to call the `ngOnInIt` method each time the `routerLink` is visited, because I am using the ID in the currently visited link to bind and retrieve data from a database and if the method is not called I lose that data.

Here is an example of my init method (sorry don't know how to use code snippets here)

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.getAuth().subscribe(auth=> {
        if(auth) {
            this.loggedInUser = auth.email;
        } else {
        }
    });

    this.teamService.getTeams().subscribe(teams => {
        this.teams = teams;
        console.log(this.teams);
        for(var i = 0; i < this.teams.length; i++) {
            if(this.teams[i].createdBy == this.loggedInUser) {
                this.myTeams.push(this.teams[i]);
            }
        }    
    });

    console.log(this.myTeams);

    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    //Get Team
    this.scrimService.getScrim(this.id).subscribe(scrim => {
        this.scrim = scrim;
    });

}
```

and here is the router-link i am using to get to this component

```
 <a *ngIf="recordOwner" [routerLink]="['/edit-scrim/'+id]" class="btn btn secondary">Edit</a>
```

I read in some answers to similar question like mine that I can use `activatedRoute.params` and `subscribe` to the data inside the constructor so that everything from `ngOnInit` method is called in the constructor, but I have no clue what that means and how to accomplish in my scenario :/

**EDIT**

```
id: string;
loggedInUser: string;

scrim: Scrim = {
name: '',
game: '',
time: '',
level: '',
description: '',
region: '',
platform: '',
acceptedBy: '',
acceptedDate: '',
acceptedStatus: '',
createdBy: '',
createdDate: '',
team: ''

}

teams: Team[];
myTeams: Team[] = [];
currentDate: string;
currentTime: string;
```

I have a service which gets "Teams" from a firebase database and returns an array of Model. I am using the currently logged in user's email address to find teams that were created by only the current user. Once i have those teams inside the array myTeams i am then trying to populate a select html tag with the team names from the myTeams list for the user to select. The first time i get to this edit-scrim page the teams in the select tag are populated just fine, but if i move to another page and comeback to this edit-scrim page using a RouterLink the select list is not populated because it doesn't call the ngoninit method again, so if i refresh my webpage the teams are populated again which i am guessing is because the ngoninit is called again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to inject the `activatedRoute` into your constructor like this,

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
params =>{
   this.id = params['id'];
   this.scrimService.getScrim(this.id).subscribe(scrim => {
        this.scrim = scrim;
    });

}
}
```

Comment: but this does not call the init method again or reloads the component :/

Comment: You need to add your api calling code to another method and call that method after the `this.id = parmas['id'];`

Comment: I updated my answer to include API call, see if it works

Comment: if possible could you contact me on FB for a little detailed explanation 
Thanks
https://www.facebook.com/makrani

Comment: You can ask here,if you need help or post another question if you have another issue, kindly mark this answer as accepted if it worked :)

Comment: It actually didn't work, i called the code from my original ngoninit method inside this subscribe method but it didn't work. Let me edit my post for more information

Comment: try console logging the  `id` your get in the `subscribe` method, also update your post to show the changes you made, it should work

Comment: try putting your code into another method and call that method in both `ngOnInit` and `subscribe` method, also do a `console.log` in `subscribe` method to see if it executes or not

Comment: is there a way to call the subscribe only on the 2nd visit? because on the first visit it is calling the newly created method both on onnginit and subscribe making my values repeat?

Comment: you can only call this method in you `subscribe` method, then the issue will be resolved